# Problem with a VB function on my form (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: vb.net, forms, function

The function I am trying to create takes in an input from a combo box (Small, Medium, Large)
and then spits out a price based on what was selected. For example, if the user chooses small the calculated price would be 100, if Medium: 200, and if Large: 300. I want the function to be executed after the user clicks the button I created "Calculate Price". I would then have a message box tell the user "The calculated price is: {result}." I currently just keep getting the output "The calculated price is: 0." upon testing my work. Here is the code I am using for the function and button click. (Note: I don't need to have the dollar amounts be returned as integers, they can just be strings Im not too picky about that)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim result As Integer
        result = calcpriceFunction(cboUnitType.ToString)
        MessageBox.Show("The calculated price is: " & result)

End Sub

Private Function calcpriceFunction(ByVal untype As String) As Integer
    Dim price As String
    untype = ""
    price = ""
    If untype = "Small" Then
        Return price = "100"
    ElseIf untype = "Medium" Then
        Return price = "200"
    ElseIf untype = "Large" Then
        Return price = "300"
    End If


End Function
```

If anyone can spot a mistake or some sort of convention flaw that would be amazing. I am all out of options right now!

Comment: _untype = ""_ clears the variable passed as parameter. So none of your if else will be true. I really suggest you to learn how to use the [Visual Studio Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/?view=vs-2022) because this error will be evident if you use this indispensable tool

Comment: Also I wonder how do you manage to compile this code. The _calcpriceFunction_ is missing the return value if none of the if else is met. This should be flagged with an error "Not all code paths return a value" or similar

Comment: @Steve I havent received any errors in the debugger. I am honestly just very confused and don't know what needs to be changed and corrected.

Comment: remove the `untype = ""` line in `calcpriceFunction`

Comment: @Steve that's only an error with `Option Strict On`, which it isn't by default.  Otherwise, the return value will be the default for the return type (0 in this case).

Comment: Speaking of `Option Strict On`, I would highly recommend turning it on.  It will flag a number of things that are potentially bugs (like the line `Return price = "100"` which will convert a boolean from the conditional `price = "100"` to an integer).

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems with *calcpriceFunction*

First of all, the code declares that function as returning an integer but instead you try to return a string. This is accepted by the compiler because in the option of your project you have the [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) set to Off and this enables automatic type conversion (when possible). While it seems a good thing, in reality this automatic conversion creates lot of problems because you will never know when, for any reason, it doesn't work as expected. So, first thing is to change that option to Option Strict On.

Then it is necessary to remove that *untype = ""* because it changes the value passed in the parameter.

Finally, don't return at each if/else statement, but just set the price value and use just one final return

```
Private Function calcpriceFunction(ByVal untype As String) As Integer
    ' Zero is the default, but I like to be explicit
    Dim price As Integer = 0

    If untype = "Small" Then
        price = 100
    ElseIf untype = "Medium" Then
        price = 200
    ElseIf untype = "Large" Then
        price = 300
    End If
    Return price
End Function
```

This change will remove the many exit points from your method but also remove another subtle bug present in the original return statement

```
Return price = "100"
```

doesn't assign the value "100" to the variable price and then return it, instead it ask the compiler to return the result of the comparison between the current value of price and the constant "100". Or in other words. Is the current value of *price* equals to "100"? If not return 0

Comment: Thank you! are there any changes I have to make in Sub button click portion? I still receive the same error with your updated changes. I really appreicate you taking the time Steve!

Comment: Just got it to work! I changed result = calcpriceFunction(cboUnitType.ToString) to result = calcpriceFunction(cboUnitType.SelectedValue)!

Comment: Yes, the cboUnitType.ToString will pass the class name of the combobox not its value

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Function calculatePrice(untype As String) As Integer
    If untype = "Small"  Then Return 100
    If untype = "Medium" Then Return 200
    If untype = "Large"  Then Return 300
    Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
End Function
```

One thing to understand early is that it's **very bad** to conflate integers and strings. `"100"` and `100` are **not the same value!** Moreover, thanks to internationalization/localization and other cultural concerns, converting back and forth between those values is *so much slower and error-prone* than you can know. It's absolutely something to avoid as much as possible.

Therefore, when accepting numeric input from a user, which of course must start as a string, convert to a numeric type like `integer` or `Decimal` *as soon as possible*, and keep it that way *as long as possible*, only convert it back to a string again when you must show it to a user again.

The same principle applies to DateTime values.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some modifications to your `calcpriceFunction`:

```
Private Function CalculatePrice(untype As String) As Integer
    Select Case untype.ToLowerInvariant
        Case "small"
            Return 100
        Case "medium"
            Return 200
        Case "large"
            Return 300
        Case Else
            Return 0
    End Select
End Function
```

In addition to the issues Steve mentioned in his answer, I suggest you make the function case-insensitive for the `untype` value. Also, I changed the condition block from `If ... ElseIf ... ElseIf ... End If` to `Select Case` for readability. Note that you can return the price directly once you have determined what it is as it is done in this example with `Return 100`. Finally, I renamed the function to `CalculatePrice`. There is no reason to abbreviate the name and you should not have `Function` in a function name.

Answer (score 0):

I made these changes to my Button Click and function and I got my desired outcome! Thank you so much everyone for the help.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim result As Integer
        result = calcpriceFunction(cboUnitType.SelectedValue)
        MessageBox.Show("The calculated price is: $" & result & " per month.")

End Sub

Private Function calcpriceFunction(ByVal untype As String) As Integer

    Dim price As Integer = 0

    If untype = "Small" Then
        price = 100
    ElseIf untype = "Medium" Then
        price = 200
    ElseIf untype = "Large" Then
        price = 300
    End If
    Return price



End Function
```

Comment: Please dont forget to accept the answer of the user which helped you solve this problem!